# Calculating the contour integral $ \int_\gamma |z|^n \, dz $ over a closed circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ denote the curve over the boundary of a  circle with midpoint $w \in \mathbb C$ . I want to calculate the contour integral
$$
\int_\gamma |z|^n \, dz
$$
for $n$ a positive integer. Is there somewhere a reference for this integral? If there is not absolute value around $z^n$ then the answer is clear.

Comment: isn't $|z|^n=1$ on your contour?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake in the question and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use complex analysis: your circle is given by $(z-w)(\bar z - \bar w) = r^2$, from which you can compute $\bar z = \frac{r^2}{z-w} +\bar w =:f(z)$. If $n=2k$ then on your circle $|z|^{2k}=z^kf(z)^k$ and you can compute $\int_\gamma z^kf(z)^k\,dz$ by residues. If $n$ is odd, you can try the same (now $k$ is a half-integer) but you will get an elliptic integral (residues will not help you because of the 2-valuedness of square roots).

Answer (score 0):

Integrate $|z|^n$.

$z= [w_x+r\cos(t)]+i[w_y+r\sin(t)]$

$dz=[-r\sin(t) +ir\cos(t)]dt$

$|z|^n=[w_x^2+w_y^2+r^2+2rw_x\cos(t)+2rw_y\sin(t)]^{n/2}$

$\int_0^{2\pi} [w_x^2+w_y^2+r^2+2rw_x\cos(t)+2rw_y\sin(t)]^{n/2}[-r\sin(t) +ir\cos(t)]dt$

That is your line integral.

For even $n$, this is a standard trig integral. For odd $n$ you get something more complicated, the elliptic integrals.